# All page content not showing after user is logged out from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am facing one issue in my wordpress site. When I am logged out from site few of the content of home page getting disappeared. Like some heading and plugins etc.

Here is my code of "About" section:

```
<?php
/**
 *  The template for displaying about section in front page.
 *
 *  @package WordPress
 *  @subpackage illdy
 */
?>
<?php
if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $general_title = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_title', __( 'About', 'illdy' ) );
    $general_entry = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_entry', __( 'It is an amazng one-page theme with great features that offers an incredible experience. It is easy to install, make changes, adapt for your business. A modern design with clean lines and styling for a wide variety of content, exactly how a business design should be. You can add as many images as you want to the main header area and turn them into slider.', 'illdy' ) );
}else{
    $general_title = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_title' );
    $general_entry = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_entry' );
}
?>

<?php if ( $general_title != '' || $general_entry != '' || is_active_sidebar( 'front-page-about-sidebar' ) ) { ?>

<section id="about" class="front-page-section" style="<?php if( !$general_title && !$general_entry ): echo 'padding-top: 130px;'; endif; ?>">
    <?php if( $general_title || $general_entry ): ?>
        <div class="section-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if( $general_title ): ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3><?php echo do_shortcode(wp_kses_post( $general_title )); ?></h3>
                        </div><!--/.col-sm-12-->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( $general_entry ): ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="section-description"><?php echo do_shortcode(wp_kses_post( $general_entry )); ?></div>
                        </div><!--/.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1-->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!--/.row-->
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!--/.section-header-->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php /*?><div class="section-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                if( is_active_sidebar( 'front-page-about-sidebar' ) ):
                    dynamic_sidebar( 'front-page-about-sidebar' );
                elseif( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) & defined("ILLDY_COMPANION") ):
                    $the_widget_args = array(
                        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 widget_illdy_skill">',
                        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                        'before_title'  => '',
                        'after_title'   => ''
                    );

                    the_widget( 'Illdy_Widget_Skill', 'title='. __( 'Testing', 'illdy' ) .'&percentage=60&icon=fa-font&color=#f18b6d', $the_widget_args );
                    the_widget( 'Illdy_Widget_Skill', 'title='. __( 'Design', 'illdy' ) .'&percentage=82&icon=fa-pencil&color=#f1d204', $the_widget_args );
                    the_widget( 'Illdy_Widget_Skill', 'title='. __( 'Development', 'illdy' ) .'&percentage=86&icon=fa-code&color=#6a4d8a', $the_widget_args );
                endif;
                ?>
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.section-content--><?php */?>
</section><!--/#about.front-page-section-->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is it something like only logged in users can see? the code is being written like that only?

Comment: no such logic is there

Comment: then post the code of the home page

Comment: This is about section code and i am unable to see heading after logout.

Comment: heading means what heading? the admin bar? or something else?

Comment: On home page, there is an about section which contains 'About us' heading and its content. When i logout of theme, 'about us' heading disappears. and if i am logged in then it appears again. Same is happening with some plugins. When i am logged out some plugins disappear from homepage

Comment: i guess its not about those things. its getting hidden due to the position; when you login the admin bar comes and then the section comes down so you can see it. check your html and css or any jquery which is creating this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code is

```
<?php
if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $general_title = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_title', __( 'About', 'illdy' ) );
    $general_entry = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_entry', __( 'It is an amazng one-page theme with great features that offers an incredible experience. It is easy to install, make changes, adapt for your business. A modern design with clean lines and styling for a wide variety of content, exactly how a business design should be. You can add as many images as you want to the main header area and turn them into slider.', 'illdy' ) );
}else{
    $general_title = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_title' );
    $general_entry = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_entry' );
}
?>
```

Please check by replacing those code with

```
<?php

    $general_title = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_title', __( 'About', 'illdy' ) );
    $general_entry = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_about_general_entry', __( 'It is an amazng one-page theme with great features that offers an incredible experience. It is easy to install, make changes, adapt for your business. A modern design with clean lines and styling for a wide variety of content, exactly how a business design should be. You can add as many images as you want to the main header area and turn them into slider.', 'illdy' ) );
?>
```

That means remove if and else section.

Comment: Glad to know this solution is working :) Please mark this as answer.